# Should functions/constants/variables be exported or not in `package main`?

Tags: go

I'm developing [a tiny project](https://github.com/JensRantil/geanstalkd) that has a single `package main`. AFAIK, best-practice for small Golang binary projects is to have all code [in a single (`main`) namespace](http://peter.bourgon.org/go-in-production/), so that's what I've done.

Just curious, within a `package main`, is it best practice to keep functions/constants/variables exported (`MyFunction`) or unexported (`myFunction`)?

Answer (score 3):

Really it doesn't matter. `main` packages can't be imported so whether you export them or not doesn't matter in that regard.

However if you do export them then tools like `golint` will encourage you to document them so maybe that's a good reason to go ahead an export them.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is to be consistent.  I prefer to name un-exported items in package main starting with lowercase even though they can't be exported. This is because it's an additional hint that these entities aren't used outside their containing package.  You don't need to know that the declaration is in main to know that the thing being declared is not used externally.